# Set up the differential equation and conditions which describe the motion of the particle given forces.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

A particle of mass 5kg moves along the x axis under the influence of two forces. Firstly,
it experiences an attractive force towards the origin O of 40 times the instantaneous distance
from O and secondly damping (or resistive force) which is 20 times the instantaneous
speed. Assume that the particle starts from 0.2m from the origin.

Set up the differential equation and conditions which describe the motion of the
particle.

So What I've tried is letting $a=8s-4v$ where $s$ is displacement, and differentiating to get $v=\frac{e^-{\frac{t+4}4}}4+2s$
Is this the right approach and if so, how can I work out $c$ cos at $t=0$ I don't know $v$, only $s$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the information provided, you should have $$5a=-40x-20v$$
$$\implies \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+4\frac{dx}{dt}+8x=0$$

This is easily solved to get a general solution. However with only one initial condition (i.e. only the value of $x$ when $t=0$) you won't be able to get a particular solution.

Comment: Why is your $40x$ -ve? Aren't the forces in opposite direction since it's a dampening force?

Comment: It also then asks; Write down the position of the particle $x$ at time $t$ and determine the period of the
oscillation, so does that not indicate that we have to find a particular solution?

Comment: acceleration and velocity are measured in the same sense as increasing displacement away from the origin. The resistance and attractive force are directed towards the origin. You can solve the DE to get an expression for displacement, and the period can be found independently of any initial conditions